# How to write a dataframe into a database having a column with quotation?

Tags: sql, database, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

with schema say -

```
'struct<address:string,"name":string>'
```

One column name say `"name"` is with quotation marks. Now while writing the df it gives :

```
name expected at the position ..  but '"' is found.
```

with following sample code :

```
df
.write
.format(format)
.options(options)
........
```

Comment: It gives more precise information if you share at least a sample of your source code

Answer (score 0):

My answer below. We are just renaming column with escape characted. You should do this just before writing to database i.e. df.write statement.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

values = [("112 Street, Pune","Stacky"),
          ("220 Street, Mumbai","John")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(values)
schema = StructType([StructField("address", StringType(), True),                             
StructField("name", StringType(), True)])

data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
data.show(20,False)

+------------------+------+
|address           |name  |
+------------------+------+
|112 Street, Pune  |Stacky|
|220 Street, Mumbai|John  |
+------------------+------+

data = data.withColumnRenamed("name","\"name\"")
data.show()

+------------------+------+
|           address|"name"|
+------------------+------+
|112 Street, Pune  |Stacky|
|220 Street, Mumbai|  John|
+------------------+------+
```

Comment: No even after using `data.withColumnRenamed("name","\"name\"")`, it shows as name expected but found `'"'` in the schema while using `data.withColumnRenamed("name","\"name\""). write....//others options` while writing to a db

Comment: Which data base are you using.?

Comment: vertica db @Manish